# Unable to merge dex error when building my project

Tags: android, gradle

im getting the Unable to merge dex error when I'm trying to build my project. I literally tried every solution on the other threads, but I couldn't find one that would work for me... So please dont mark this as a duplicate right away.

So here is the exact error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
> java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex
```

My build.gradle(project) file:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

and my module build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    //buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.leodr.upgradeadmin"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

As external libraries i use GSON.

Comment: Please add rest part of error log if it has more lines. Some classes are duplicate and they should appear in the log. Also need to know you are using external libraries.

Comment: there is not more, just the error i copied into the question. I looked only in the "Messages Gradle Build" section, or is there any other place where i can see the errors?

Comment: why did you commented your buildTools? add buildToolsVersion '27.0.1' and clean your project

Comment: maybe related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47360856/unable-to-merge-dex-android-studio-3-0-build-error/47383686#47383686 To get stacktrace: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21674091/how-to-add-stacktrace-or-debug-option-when-building-android-studio-project

Comment: error is still there...

Comment: Please post dependencies tree. To get dependency tree: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39008887/how-do-i-show-dependencies-tree-in-android-studio/39020703

Answer (score 0):

**Tried to enable multidex**

modify your build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
}

defaultConfig {
    multiDexEnabled true

}
```

in your manifiest file define your apllication name properrty like this

```
android:name="com.pkg.YouApplication"
```

Include this in your Application class

```
public class YouApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
        super.attachBaseContext(base);
        MultiDex.install(this);
    }

}
```